# How to DRY exception handling with Java 8 CompletableFuture when code throws exception?

Tags: java, java-8, future, dry, completable-future

I don't know about you guys but, for me it become very annoying when I see a piece of code that is `repeated` and I came across the following scenario when using `Services` that throw exception. As shown below, in each `CompletableFuture` block I have to do `exception handling` and that part is basically repeated over and over depending on how many completable futures you are going to have.

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future1Of15 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    List<SomePojo> somePojos = null;
    try {
        somePojos = someServiceThatThrowsException.getAll(SomePojo.class);
    } catch (SomeException e) {
       //Handle the exception
       e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return somePojos; 
}).thenAcceptAsync(result -> //do something with the result); 

CompletableFuture<Void> future2Of15 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    List<OtherPojo> otherPojos = null;
    try {
        otherPojos = someServiceThatThrowsException.getAll(OtherPojo.class);
    } catch (SomeException e) {
           //Handle the exception
           e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return otherPojos; 
}).thenAcceptAsync(result -> //do something with the result);
```

Now repeat the above `x` number of times and you notice that, the `try/catch` block is repeated. In my case, I have around `15-20` such calls.

Is there a way that I could turn the above into 1 or 2 lines of code? In order words `stop repeating myself` with regards to `exception handling` inside the `supplyAsync lambda`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a method to your class that does all of the repeated code, and takes a `Consumer<List<?>>` as an argument to pass to `thenAcceptAsync` on the last line.

```
private CompletableFuture<Void> getAndAcceptAsync(Consumer<List<?>> resultProcessor) {  
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        List<SomePojo> somePojos = null;
        try {
            somePojos = someServiceThatThrowsException.getAll(SomePojo.class);
        } catch (SomeException e) {
           //Handle the exception
           e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return somePojos; 
    }).thenAcceptAsync(resultProcessor);
}
```

You can then call this as many times as you need to.

```
future1Of15 = getAndAcceptAsync(result-> { do something } );
future2Of15 = getAndAcceptAsync(result-> { do something else } );
```

Comment: I like the Consumer idea.

Answer (score 2):

There are *patterns* for handling effects like e.g. failure in functional programming. One such pattern is the `Try` monad for which e.g. [vavr](http://vavr.io) provides an implementation in java.

Those patterns abstract a lot of boilerplate away from you via declarative apis:

```
CompletableFuture
    .supplyAsync(() -> Try.of(() -> methodThatThrows()))
    .thenAccept(res -> System.out.println(res));
```

Or if you aren't bound to using `CompletableFuture`, you may choose to use the `Future` monad to further reduce boilerplate code:

```
Future.of(() -> methodThatThrows())
    .onComplete(result -> System.out.println(result));
```

Either way, what you end up with as the result of that `Future<T>` is a `Try<T>`, which can be either a `Success<T>` or a `Failure` which you can deal with accordingly.

Comment: I prefer `CompletableFuture` because of the different stages and features in comparison to `Future`. I didn't knew about the `vavr` though, thanks for sharing. I am going to see how `vavr` fits into the projects that I am working on.

Comment: @Raf In fact, you can call `toCompletableFuture()` on the vavr `Future`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not claim that this is the only approach or the most effective approach, I am sharing the solution that helped me `DRY` and it might or might not work for you. If you have a better solution, please share it.

I created the following utility method

```
@Component
public class CompletableFutureUtil {
    @Autowired
    private SomeGenericServiceThatThrowsException genericService; 

    public <T> CompletableFuture<Collection<T>> fireupCompletableFutureAsynchronously(Class<T> type) {
        CompletableFuture<Collection<T>> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            Collection<T> mystery = null;
            try {
                mystery = genericService.list(type); 
            } catch (SomeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                //Handle the exception
            } 
            return mystery; 
        }); 
        return future; 
    }
}
```

And now I can reuse the above utility method in the following way after `autowiring` it

```
@Autowired private CompletableFutureUtil futureUtil;
```

The calls basically become one to two lines max

```
futureUtil.fireupCompletableFutureAsynchronously(SomePojo.class)
                .thenAcceptAsync(result -> //do something with result); 

futureUtil.fireupCompletableFutureAsynchronously(OtherPojo.class)
                .thenAcceptAsync(result -> //do something with result);
```

Happy `DRY+ing`